# I want to count ocurrences of a Text in a Field in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb

In MariaDB, I want to insert count ocurrences of a Text in a Field in another table.
something like:

```
Insert Into UniqueFacts (Text, Frecuency) 
(SELECT DISTINCT(Fact) , count(*)  FROM AllFacts group by Fact)
```

But this sentence no insert frecuencies.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`DISTINCT` is not a function.  What you have is the same as

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       Fact, COUNT(*)
    FROM ...
```

`DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` are always(?) redundant with each other.

To fix your query, simply remove one word: `DISTINCT`; keep the `GROUP BY`.